# How to get specific hour for hourly scheduled spark job with spark coordinator

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, oozie, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

I'm spending a day finding why my coordinator not working as expected, and still not get any clue.

I want to have 2 spark jobs run respectively with the second job is dependents on the first job. I have completed the first job to produce `_SUCCESS` file hourly. The problem is when the second job finding its dependency, it got the wrong `HOUR`. It is always picking up `00` instead of the hour at the execution time.

here is sample of the xml part for the second job dependency

```
<datasets>
<dataset name="\first_job" frequency="${coord:days(1)}" initial-instance="2015-01-01T00:00Z" timezone="GMT">
  <uri-template>hdfs://nameservice1/user/user/project/first_job/success/${YEAR}${MONTH}${DAY}/${HOUR}</uri-template>
  <done-flag>_SUCCESS</done-flag>
</dataset>
```

and here is some log

```
::CoordActionInputCheck:: Missing deps:hdfs://nameservice1/user/user/project/first_job/success/20171222/00/_SUCCESS
```

please advise me for what I'm doing wrong or what I have missed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have set the frequency to `frequency="${coord:days(1)}"`, it means your oozie coordinator needs to trigger job only once at 00 hour, thats why it always looking for the starting hour of the day which is `00` hours from your initial instance. 
Use the [hours](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a4.4._Frequency_and_Time-Period_Representation) EL function

```
frequency="${coord:hours(1)}"
```

to instruct co ordinator to check for every hour.

Also, the initial-instance set is to `initial-instance="2015-01-01T00:00Z"` and frequency is 1 day, so it will increment the by 1 day but hours will be same `00:00Z`. Change this time to pick a particular hours.